# Various releases of Punisher: War Zone

Tags: alternate-version, punisher-war-zone

I watched yesterday some parts of Punisher: War Zone on Netflix and I noticed that at least one sentence changed since last time some months ago, again on Netflix.

Spoiler of course...

> About the end, when Frank Castle speaks with Micro while pointing the gun at him, the speech now is "you won't feel a thing, Micro". In the previous version available on Netflix, the text was "it won't be the same without you".

I'm listening to the original English version. The mouth follows the speech, at least in the version currently on Netflix.

Is there a list of the different releases of the film with also a detail of the differences?